# Return a number that is a roundup

Tags: python

Python program that will take two numbers: a and b.Return a number that is
a roundup version of a so that it is multiple of b:
Examples:

```
a=13, b = 5, return 15.
a=15, b = 3, return 15
a = 16, b = 3, returns 18'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
Research before you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil):

```
import math

def round_up(a,b):
  return math.ceil(a/b) * b

print(round_up(13, 3))
print(round_up(16, 3))
```

Output:

```
15
18
```